# Scroll a textarea using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to append text into a textarea

```
var box = $('<textarea></textarea>')
    .attr({id: 'log_viewer',
           readonly: '',
       cols: 100,
       rows: 40})
    .appendTo($(outputEntity));
```

When data is received from a WebSocket, it's appended to the content of the textarea:

```
 ws.onmessage = function(msg) { 
     var data = decodeURIComponent(msg.data);

     data = data.replace('<', '&lt;');
     data = data.replace('>', '&gt;');

     box.append(data);
 }
```

What I need is for this box to scroll to the bottom automatically, so that the viewport is always centered on the last page of output.  Following some other Stack Overflow suggestions on this topic, I tried:

```
 $('#log_viewer').scrollTop = $('#log_viewer')[0].scrollHeight - $('#log_viewer').height();
```

However, that doesn't work -- at least, not in Chrome or Firefox on Linux, which is all I have access to.  The box doesn't scroll.

How do I make this box auto-scroll to the bottom-most page from JS?  Is using append() to add output somehow interfering with the underlying dimension detection mechanisms?  Is append() even the right way to go there?

Or perhaps I should use not use a textarea at all, but rather a DIV with a scroll bar?  Admittedly, I'm rather behind the times on HTML + CSS and don't know exactly how to best accomplish that and still get the monospace-formatted, wrapped output I'm after.

Thanks much for any suggestions!

Comment: To get monospace-formatted, wrapped text in an element, use a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) and give it the CSS style [`white-space: normal;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to allow its text to wrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOLVED:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ua9qc/

```
var h1 = $('#log_viewer')[0].scrollHeight,
h2 = $('#log_viewer').height();

$('#log_viewer').scrollTop(h1 - h2);`
```

Comment: That's identical to the method I mentioned that I had already tried.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: No it's not ... you do `...scrollTop = x` ... I'm doing `...scrollTop (x)`. Please pay attention cuz it does work... check the fiddle.

Comment: Hi, I did implement it exactly as you suggested.  I suppose I should not have used the word "identical", then--sorry, that was very unclear of me.  Regardless, it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexBalashov The [linked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua9qc/) works for me in Chrome 29, Firefox 23, and IE 10 on Windows. When I load and reload the jsFiddle page, the `textarea` is always scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: No problem at all Alex, that's the kind of thing that happens to me all the time. In what browser version are you trying?

Comment: The fiddle works for me too.  But it doesn't work in my environment.  Most odd.

Comment: In my experimentation on my side, $('#log_viewer')[0].scrollHeight always equals 0.

Comment: All right, the error here was definitely between keyboard and chair; I am an idiot. I did not realise that I had another DOM element also called log_viewer. I was trying to scroll a SPAN, not the TEXTAREA.

Comment: ... happens to me all the time ...  :)

Comment: great, thank you - took me 2 hours of playtime to find this. Works well with percentages, too (as a scrollspy on something else).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help you. If you wanna scroll certain element at the bottom, you can use this function to scroll by passing div id. Add these function to script

```
function scrollme(id)
{
     var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');
     var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset-100}, 1000, function() {

          });
}
function scrollableElement(els)
{
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
}
```